# Struggling with assets folders

Tags: android, directory, assets, directory-listing

I've been struggling with a simple assets directory listing. I have the following structure (roughly speaking):

```
-dirA
--data.xml
--AudioSUBdir
---some files here
--VideoSUBdir
---some files here
-dirB
--data.xml
--AudioSUBdir
---some files here
-test    
--SUBtestDir
```

All I want is a listing of the parent asset directory (i.e. dirA, dirB, and test; I will then read the data.xml files and on basis of this do something with the content of the subdirs).

I thought that getting the desired two strings would be easy:

```
try {
   String[] fileNames;
   fileNames = getAssets().list("");
   for(String name:fileNames){
      // process it, e.g. write it out }
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

However, what I'm getting is something like AudioSUBdir, dirA, dirB, VideoSUBdir, webkit (there ain't no damned webkit at all!)
It seems to be doing several weird things at the same time:

- it ignores the directory structure, i.e. reads even subdirectories where it shouldn't
- it magically displays a webkit directory although there is none whatsoever in the entire project folder
- it ignores the "test" directory completely

So my questions are two (and a half)

1. how do I get just the root folders (I want to later test them for existence of the file folder/data.xml, which will be processed and the application will do whatever it's supposed to)
2. any explanation of what is going on. I could theoretically deal with the fact that it even writes out subdirs although I don't want them. I could even get over the fact that it ignores the test folder (perhaps because they are empty? - Well empty, containing just a subdir, not a file, but anyway...) But where the hell is the webkit folder coming from? Is it somehow "post-generated" by the apk buidling process?
3. I'm getting a feeling that all subfolders are actually collapsed into one root. Does it mean that files of the same name will collide during the building process?

Comment: Have you tried checking the directory structure manually with `adb shell`? This gives you a Linux command-line shell to the devices directory structure. You can `cd` to `/data/data/<project-name>/assets` to view the files directly.

Comment: Same as Code-Guru, I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Well, I'm working on Windows so what I've done is that I, of course, manually checked the directory structure (generated by Eclipse). But it creates normal directories as expected. Yet, the directory listing does what I described above.

Comment: AssetManager is brain dead.  Your observation is correct.  The only way I found of getting around this is to write my own recursive search.  If you need it (it's easy to do), let me know and I'll dig it up.  BTW, assets at runtime is virtual and is merged with "your" assets directory, so you will see stuff you did not put in there.

Comment: The recursive search in the assets would be appreciated as I'm not sure how to do anything recursive on something that seems to have been flattened out of any structure :(

Comment: I've posted it as an answer since I can't do it in a comment ;)  BTW, it's not flattened.  Step through the code and examine the 'files' string array.

Comment: @Simon, I don't see your answer. But anyway, I seem to be able to resolve my particular problem right now. But I still don't quite understand how getAssets and list work. Why do they display sub-dirs (but only display files in these dirs if the sub-dir is specified in the list argument). Any hint where I could learn what to expect from the getAssets without having to play a guessing game with the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the 1st (and major) issue of my question is concerned, I think I've figured it out.

```
try {
   String[] fileNames;
   fileNames = MyAudioGuideApplication.this.getAssets().list("");
   for(String name:fileNames){
       if (Arrays.asList(getResources().getAssets().list(name)).contains("data.xml"))
        process.the.file.here
   }
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

I'm still not sure how exactly getAssets works but at least the following seems to turn out:

- folders are ignored if they contain no files
- output is sorted alphabetically regardless the structure
- when called from the root folder - i.e. ...list("") - it lists even subdirectories

Maybe it can help someone struggling as I have.